Redis and time series with spring boot and lettuce
I want to store time series data daily in Redis (or try it out at least) I have a set up with lettuce and its working fine with the RedisTemplate.
But I'm not sure where to begin with time series data or how to do work with it.
I have data as such:
12-10-2024

{
   [value 1, value 2, value 3].  // list
}

13-10-2024

{
   [value 14, value 25, value 35] // list
}

would this be possible in redis using time series, i only need 28 days of data and so every day i add another day and the the earliest can be removed.
I want to be able to get the range of data from x day to y day, and the speed redis gives would be perfect. Id like to try it atleast.
Can this be done? Anyone got any ideas? or done this?

There is no way (yet) to use the RedisTemplate in Spring Data Redis to execute TimeSeries commands directly. You could, however, use the RedisTemplate.execute() method or use raw driver access and call the commands yourself, in any of the ways described in Spring data redis support for modules?.
Obviously you would also have to use either Redis Stack or Redis 8.0-M01 as starting from version 8 Redis integrates all the search, vector search, JSON data modeling, time series and probabilistic data structure features. Older versions of the Redis server do not support the TimeSeries feature.
Specifically in your example you could issue the following commands:
127.0.0.1:6379> TS.CREATE 12-10-2024 LABELS type myts 
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> EXPIRE 12-10-2024 2419200
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> TS.ADD 12-10-2024 * 1
(integer) 1730286391658
127.0.0.1:6379> TS.ADD 12-10-2024 * 2
(integer) 1730286395037
127.0.0.1:6379> TS.ADD 12-10-2024 * 3
(integer) 1730286396945


127.0.0.1:6379> TS.CREATE 13-10-2024 LABELS type myts
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> EXPIRE 13-10-2024 2419200
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> TS.ADD 13-10-2024 * 14
(integer) 1730286431724
127.0.0.1:6379> TS.ADD 13-10-2024 * 25
(integer) 1730286435996
127.0.0.1:6379> TS.ADD 13-10-2024 * 35
(integer) 1730286441010

127.0.0.1:6379> TS.MRANGE 1730286247950 1730286431724 FILTER type=myts
1) 1) "12-10-2024"
   2) (empty array)
   3) 1) 1) (integer) 1730286391658
         2) 1
      2) 1) (integer) 1730286395037
         2) 2
      3) 1) (integer) 1730286396945
         2) 3
2) 1) "13-10-2024"
   2) (empty array)
   3) 1) 1) (integer) 1730286431724
         2) 14

In this sample we create two time series, both having the same label myts, and then we query on the label between timestamps, resulting in a cross time-series result (the result of the TS.MRANGE command).

what about sortedset?

Sorted sets are naturally sorted; however, they miss all time-series-related features available using the specialized time-series data structure. If you want to perform a range search spanning multiple time series, you must implement your logic if you resort to the sorted set. Time-series has it out of the box, together with additional useful commands.
